# Does this always converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, algebraic-geometry, convergence-divergence, triangles

So, I was researching the whole quadrature thing recently and decided to define right triangles area(with legs a and b) as a sum of the inscribed square and two smaller triangles.

[Square inscribed in right triangle with legs a and b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wovsg.png)

To find its area I have defined following recursive expression:

$$S\bigl(a, b\bigr) = \bigl(\frac{ab}{a+b}\bigr)^2 + S\bigl(\frac{a^2}{a+b}, \frac{b}{a+b}\bigr) + S\bigl(\frac{ab}{a+b}, \frac{b^2}{a+b}\bigr)$$

And, as I was trying to find S(a, b) in finite terms(and assuming that I don't know that it is $\frac{ab}{2}$), expanding S on the right side, I came up to following:

$$S\bigl(a, b\bigr) = \bigl(\frac{ab}{a+b}\bigr)^2\sum_{i=0}^\infty \biggl(\frac{a^2}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(a+b)^2}\biggr)^i$$
And thus, $S\bigl(a, b\bigr) = \frac{ab}{2}$

But what if we don't limit this problem to just positive a and b?

Does it converge?

And to what it converges?

**Edit: Typo in series**

Comment: $$S(a,b) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a^2}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{b^2}{(a+b)^2}\right)$$

What is $i$ here?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to put it there before. Now it is where it belongs

Comment: Your sum does not converge to the right area, so I think you may have missed some terms somewhere, or messed up on some algebra. If you work out the sum you have written (it's a geometric series) it comes out to $1 + 2(a/b + b/a)$. If you look at the picture of what's going on geometrically, it pretty clearly converges to the area of the triangle.

Comment: Thank you for noting the typo) It is obvious that for positive a and b S(a, b) converges to a triangle, but what happens when we do not limit a and b to just positive numbers?

Comment: @SardorGulyamov I have edited my answer according to your typo fix.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, for $S$ to be well defined we need $a+b \neq 0$. For each $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}$, $\bar{S}(a,b) := S(a,b)(\frac{a+b}{ab})^2$ is nothing more than a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). It will converge if and only if

$$
\big|\frac{a^2+b^2}{(a+b)^2}\big| = \frac{a^2+b^2}{(a+b)^2} < 1
$$

This will occur if $a^2 + b^2 < (a+b)^2 = a^2 +2ab + b^2$, that is, when $2ab >0$. Therefore, both $a$ and $b$ have to share the same sign and be nonzero. As for the value of convergence, since we're dealing with a geometric series,

$$
\bar{S}(a,b) = \frac{1}{1-\frac{a^2+b^2}{(a+b)^2}} = \frac{1}{\frac{2ab}{(a+b)^2}} = \frac{(a+b)^2}{2ab} 
$$

Now,

$$
S(a,b) =  \big(\frac{ab}{a+b}\big)^2\bar{S}(a,b) = \frac{a^2b^2}{2ab} = \frac{ab}{2}
$$

like predicted. To sum up, the biggest domain we can consider is $D := \{(a,b) : ab > 0\}$, and here $S(a,b) = \frac{ab}{2}$, coinciding with the values known for positive $a$ and $b$.